# Automatically populate cell in Google Sheets when another cell in same row is manually filled but error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I want to create a macro that will automatically populate a column in each row when another column in that row is manually filled. The autofilled cell will use a formula that import from other googlesheet file and using query to import the data. I currently using script but i cant put a apostrof to complete my formula

`

```
function onEdit(e) { //Runs every time the sheet is edited
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DB Mitra'); //Change this to whatever your sheet is named
  var inputCol = sheet.getRange('B2'); //Change this to whatever column the date is going to be entered

  //This is the range that will be checked. Slightly redundant, but makes it easier to reuse this script without needing to retype every variable
  var myRange = inputCol;

  //Get the row & column indexes of the active cell
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  //Check that your edited cell is within the correct column
  if (col == myRange.getColumn()) { //This runs only if a value is entered into the column defined in 'inputCol'
    if(sheet.getRange(e.range.getA1Notation()).getValue() == '') {return}; //If the edited cell is empty (ie the date is deleted, nothing happens)
    if(row == 1) {return} //If the header is changed, nothing happens
    let codeCell = sheet.getRange('D'+row); //Change to the column that will store the generated code value
   
    codeCell.setValue('=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1-K_ZltvOev2t9iqKIOHR8B-PY6ODBKYAwTjaDzLbHJE";"2022!B2:T494")};"SELECT Col4 WHERE Col1 = '"&B'+row+'&"'")');
    //let hardValue = codeCell.getValue(); //Gets the value from the formula you just entered
    //codeCell.setValue(hardValue); //Replaces the formula with just the resulting value
  };
}
```

`
the formula should be like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QUDz.jpg)

but it always error if i put it like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aW0m.jpg)

Thank you for anyone willing to help me. credit to [Automatically populate cell in Google Sheets when another cell in same row is manually filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72659463/automatically-populate-cell-in-google-sheets-when-another-cell-in-same-row-is-ma) for the inspiration code

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful. About your current issue. I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize, again.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, how about modifying using the template literals as follows?

#### From:

```
codeCell.setValue('=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1-K_ZltvOev2t9iqKIOHR8B-PY6ODBKYAwTjaDzLbHJE";"2022!B2:T494")};"SELECT Col4 WHERE Col1 = '"&B'+row+'&"'")');
```

#### To:

```
codeCell.setValue(`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1-K_ZltvOev2t9iqKIOHR8B-PY6ODBKYAwTjaDzLbHJE";"2022!B2:T494")};"SELECT Col4 WHERE Col1 = '"&B${row}&"'")`);
```

or

```
codeCell.setFormula(`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1-K_ZltvOev2t9iqKIOHR8B-PY6ODBKYAwTjaDzLbHJE";"2022!B2:T494")};"SELECT Col4 WHERE Col1 = '"&B${row}&"'")`);
```

#### Reference:

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)